# Folding a linked list using a Stack

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list, singly-linked-list

Here is my program to fold a linked list using a Stack:

```
    public Node middle(Node head) {
            Node slow = head;
            Node fast = head;
            while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
                fast = fast.next.next;
                slow = slow.next;
            }
            return slow;
        }

        public Node foldList(Node head){
            Node mid = middle(head);
            Node f = mid.next;
            Stack<Node> stacks = new Stack<>();
            if (head == null) return head;
            while (f != null){
                stacks.push(f);
                f = f.next;
            }
            Node temp = head;
            Node forv = head.next;
            while(!stacks.isEmpty()) {
                temp.next = stacks.pop();
                temp = temp.next;
                temp.next = forv;
                temp = temp.next;
                forv = forv.next;
            }
            return head;
        }
```

Here is the code of the middle() and foldList() methods. When I run it it gets stuck in an infinite loop. Can anybody help me find out why this is happening?

Comment: What is 'folding a linked list'? What is a 'dry run'?

Comment: if foldList is called with head == null you will get a NullPointerException when referencing mid.next(). So the if(head == null) condition a few lines down will never be met. I think you should  move that condition to the first line of foldList.

Comment: So folding is: 1-2-3-4-5-6 becomes 1-6-2-5-3-4 ?

Comment: thank you for the help. yes folding a linked list is the same as you are guessing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing this:

```
linked list: 1-2-3-4-5-6
```

Put second half in a Stack:

```
linked list: 1-2-3-4-5-6
stack: 5-6
```

Insert the stack nodes between the linked list nodes:

```
linked list: 1-6-2-3-4-5-6-2-3-4-5-6-2-3-4-5-6.....infinite
```

You need to remove the second half of the nodes (the ones put on the stack) from the linked list before you start folding.

Since it's a linked list, you can simply nullify mid.next:

```
   public Node foldList(Node head){
        Node mid = middle(head);
        Node f = mid.next;

        // remove the second half
        mid.next = null

        Stack<Node> stacks = new Stack<>();
        if (head == null) return head;
        while (f != null){
            stacks.push(f);
            f = f.next;
        }
```

Here's my full code, using Deque instead of Stack (because Stack is old and moldy):

```
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Deque;

public class LinkedListFolder {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Node head = createLinkedList();
        foldList(head);
        print(head);
    }

    private static Node createLinkedList() {
        Node head = new Node(1);
        Node current = head;
        for (int i = 2; i < 7; i++) {
            current.next = new Node(i);
            current = current.next;
        }
        return head;
    }

    private static void print(Node node) {
        System.out.println(node);
        while (node.next != null) {
            node = node.next;
            System.out.println(node);
        }
    }

    public static void foldList(Node head) {
        if (head == null) {
            return;
        }
        Deque<Node> nodesToFold = getNodesToFold(head);
        Node current = head;
        Node successor = head.next;
        while (!nodesToFold.isEmpty()) {
            current.next = nodesToFold.pop();
            current = current.next;
            current.next = successor;
            current = current.next;
            successor = successor.next;
        }
    }

    private static Deque<Node> getNodesToFold(Node head) {
        Node middle = findMiddle(head);
        Node current = middle.next;
        middle.next = null;
        Deque<Node> nodesToFold = new ArrayDeque<>();
        while (current != null) {
            nodesToFold.push(current);
            current = current.next;
        }
        return nodesToFold;
    }

    public static Node findMiddle(Node head) {
        Node slow = head;
        Node fast = head;
        while (fast != null && fast.next != null) {
            fast = fast.next.next;
            slow = slow.next;
        }
        return slow;
    }


    static class Node {
        public int value;

        public Node next;

        public Node(int value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("Node{value=%d}", value);
        }

    }
}
```

Output:

```
Node{value=1}
Node{value=6}
Node{value=2}
Node{value=5}
Node{value=3}
Node{value=4}
```

Comment: very much thank you for the help . Just one line had to add mid.next = null . and problem solved. **thanks for help.**